# In bootstrap, why is .container inside .navbar wider than regular .container in page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

With Bootstrap 4, I'm trying to put a .container inside my .navbar, so that my navbar background color can go all the way across the screen, while my navbar buttons can align left with my page content.

However, I found they don't actually align, because such a container in navbar is 30px wider than the regular containers on the page (they both change width on each breakpoint, but the difference is always 30px, except on the xs breakpoint). What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- navbar contents -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- page contents -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `.container-fluid` class instead of `.container`. The bootstrap documentation for [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) explains this in their first bullet point "use .container for a responsive pixel width or .container-fluid for width: 100% across all viewport and device sizes."

Answer (score 0):

As seen in: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/navbars/

Containers in `.navbar-expand-xx` remove the left and right padding.

That's why containers in your content do not align with a container in you navbar. A non-solution is to remove the class `navbar-expand-xx`.

A hacky solution would by to add `.px-3` to the container which adds `1rem` on both sides(about 15px).

You can check in the variables.scss that `$grid-gutter-width` is in fact 30px. In _grid.scss you'll find that, that value is divided by 2 to make the gutters.

You are not doing anything wrong here, its by design.